# In my MongoDB project i'm facing this problem: "DELETE http://localhost:5000/user/undefined 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: mongodb, fetch

I am calling a ***DELETE request*** using ***fetch***. But The request is not working. How can i solve this? Please help me!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to put the params manual it is looking like you didn't send correct params into the methods **(/user/undifined)** the undifined mean you didn't send the id for deleting the user